# Small bug in cleanup user scripts

Tags: discussion, cleanup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Another small bug in the oli's cleanup user script](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2679/another-small-bug-in-the-olis-cleanup-user-script)

I may have run across a small bug in the user script.

These six have been given to me to review, and remain on my list

https://askubuntu.com/questions/50504/sound-problems-in-unity-input-but-no-output

[Panel theme reverts to standard GNOME in indicator area](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60540/panel-theme-reverts-to-standard-gnome-in-indicator-area)

[How do I get to which window I am hovering over?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35761/how-do-i-get-to-which-window-i-am-hovering-over)

[Panel theme reverts to standard GNOME in indicator area](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60540/panel-theme-reverts-to-standard-gnome-in-indicator-area)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/50504/sound-problems-in-unity-input-but-no-output

[Ubuntu One refuses my 11 character login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61577/ubuntu-one-refuses-my-11-character-login)

These remain in "My Open Allocations" , but have been closed , 3 hours ago as of the time of this post.

Otherwise, nice user script Oli

=)