# Another small bug in the oli's cleanup user script

Tags: discussion, cleanup

The user Alvar deleted the question

https://askubuntu.com/questions/46280/

It remains on "My Open Allocations"

I can "give up" and remove it, but will leave it for the moment, not sure if you wish to look at this or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I fixed this.

A couple of days ago there was a bug in the close-detection code that I fixed. I then needed to fix a load of allocations manually but it turns out I did some of those wrong (234 of them to be precise) and forgot to set some data that would remove them from people's allocated lists. I've just fixed those manually so they shouldn't be showing on your list now.

Let me know if you're seeing the right things now.

Comment: Oli my list looks great, thank you fpr the user script. 234 ???!? Please let us know if we can help.